# Should I tell recruiter where I have decided to go?

Tags: hiring-process, internship

I accepted an offer from Company A.

Company B is asking where I decided to go and what made me make that decision.

Is there any harm to letting them know?

Answer (score 6):

> Should I tell recruiter where I have decided to go?

No, it's none of their business. Information is valuable, you don't give it out without a clear reason and idea of how it will benefit you.

Additionally you would be giving away information that involves your employer to another company.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Seems very sensible to me. Understanding where what and how much information is needed is an essential part of professional responsibilities.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't tell them where, but telling them why may help them. If they're honest about wanting to know why so that they can address their deficiencies then that certainly can't do any harm.

Comment: The why part might even help yourself if they follow up on your feedback in case you'll be reconsidering them a few years down the line. Say you are missing parking places to get there by car or they are not flexible enough to support you as a parent etc., they might adapt and be more suitable next time you consider working with them.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I tell recruiter where I have decided to go?

If he asks: sure, why not?  I liked the recruiter for Company B, so I'm willing to talk to him. As it happens I told him I was going to Company A because their product, and therefore what I'd be working on, better aligned with my interests.

I'd tell anyone that, even a bunch of unknown people on the internets.  It's not a big secret that I will be  working for Company A.  In a short time it's even going to show up on my Linked-In page, which is how the Company B recruiter found me in the first place.

(Answer based in very recent fact)

Comment: Also keeping an honest and approachable conversation with Company B might lead to a future job there if things don't work out as expected on Company A.

Answer (score 1):

If Company B decides to hire someone else instead of you, should they tell you who they hired and what made them hire that person?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I tell recruiter where I have decided to go?

Yes, you can tell them where & why you want to go. This shall lead to a healthy conversation about why you decided to go and maybe your present employer can come up with a new offer to retain you. Or it will also help the present employer decide actions for future cases.

> Is there any harm to letting them know?

This purely depends on your relations and how you are ending up with the present employer. If you are parting nicely and ethically then there should not be any problem on company level (your HR or manager's individual level response cannot be predicted on such short info mentioned in question).

Comment: I don't think the OP is leaving B for A. It appears that nz applied to A and B (and maybe C, D, and E), and chose A. Note the tags on the question   Your advice might be good, just not relevant to this question.

Comment: @Damila In that case, telling company B that he is going for company A will enable company B to revise their offer to nz if company B is desperate hiring nz.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell them in the most general terms, but you don't have to name the other company.

It's just like when a stranger you've just struck up a conversation asks where you live. You give them a general answer, but not your exact address (even if they keep on asking for a more detailed location).

Call it healthy paranoia or a healthy boundary. But if they really want to find out the name, you can just tell them to follow you on LinkedIn. You'll post that information eventually on there.

And like someone else on here has already said, it's not like they themselves routinely give out the real reasons or the real name of the winning candidate to the other losing candidates when asked. So whatever information you do end up giving them, even in the most general terms, I'm quite sure that it will be more than they would have been willing to give you had the situation been reversed.